# How to prepare HDD for Windows 8 install?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-8

I would like to keep my Linux partitions and install Windows 8 (currently have XP) to another partition.

I tried it on another computer, where I had a Linux partition, but didn't need to keep it. There was also an XP partition, but that wasn't good enough for Win8. The Windows 8 partitioner is... not very good and only allowed me to create a new Windows partition to install to after deleting all previous partitions.

Any ideas how I could prepare the partition setup in such a way that Windows 8 would just use some of the ready made partitions and leave my Ubuntu install alone?

(Sorry if dup, could only find ones for doing it the other way.)

Update:

The error I get is 0x803000024. Google returns results where the "solution" is always either to unplug all other drives (I got this with only one HDD) or remove all partitions (which I'm trying to avoid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve this in the end. I'm not sure the following are all strictly required, but it's what worked for me.

1. Make sure the target drive is the first, numbered 0 in the Win8 installer. Switch drive order via BIOS or swapping SATA connectors if necessary.
2. Make sure no GPT drives are connected if installing to MBR drive. Presumably vice versa.
3. Remove/don't create the target partition, leave empty space where you want it.
4. In the installer, don't create a partition, but choose the empty space and click next. Necessary partition(s) will be automatically created.

Answer (score 2):

By default the Windows installer creates 2 partitions, one small "System Reserved" and a big one where you install windows and where the rest of files go. You can force it to use only one partition by creating it beforehand by using for example [gparted [image: Install gparted]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted). You need to make sure that it is a ntfs primary partition.

Now if you start windows setup, point to the partition you made beforehand and it should install without partitioning anything.

Comment: Yes, I see that it created two partitions, however I had one partition (where XP was) that was a primary partition (named sda2 in Ubuntu) in NTFS format and it refused to use it, giving some opaque error number. Googling the number only returned others seeing it and needing to remove all partitions they had.

Comment: BTW, forcing it to use one gparted-prepared partition used to work with XP and even Windows 8 Preview, but doesn't with my current Windows 8 install image.

Comment: could you put this information, including the error message you get into the question?

Comment: I don't have the error number, I'll see if I can retry get it.

Comment: Ok, found the error number and updated question.

Comment: if you are using gparted, can you make sure that the boot flag is set on that ntfs partition?

Comment: Yes, boot flag is set.

Comment: I'm clueless... Also I am going to request that this question be moved to superuser because it is clearly not Ubuntu related...

Comment: are you using usb or cd and how did you create it?